# Should the CNN take all the inputs used for training to predict new samples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I just have a question on CNN which is should the model take all inputs used in training to predict new sample? what if i want to build a system for a hospital that predicts the disease from image and some features such as age and height but the user doesn’t need to enter the features in case they are not available, so he can input the image only. Is that possible to do that in CNN? because as I know all input used for training should be entered for testing and predicting new data

Answer (score 0):

As I understood as per your description you want to predict the age and height from the image of patience. In that case for training, you need proper data and model. In model training, you have to specify X_train, Y_train at least. From there, the model will learn.

**X_train - provided image of a person**

**Y_train(label) -  the characteristic you want to provide (height & age)**

For predicting purposes you have to modify the input image the same as you did before for X_train. then if you feed it into a trained model it will give you the prediction of height & age.

Comment: No, what I want to do is predicting the disease from mixed data which are features such as age and weight and the image. However, I want the system to be more flexible that means the user don’t need to enter age and weight (in case he doesn’t know their values) and just enter the image.